# ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush not working?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to set the background of a page to the default theme color selected by the user
I use:

```cs
Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
```

But this just returns a transparent background. Isnt this the correct way to the default theme color?

Comment: Also, FWIW, it shouldn't be transparent, it is either white/black (ish) unless you've specifically overridden the value of the brush.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows 8-8.1 answer**

No in fact the accent color selected by the user is not accessible to Windows Store apps.

**Windows 10 answer**

`(Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]` gives you the current accent color and you can monitor for changes using the `new UISettings().ColorValuesChanged` event.